# Can you delete your own chat comment for any reason of concern?

Tags: discussion, support

You can delete at any time (main and meta page) personal answers and comments and sometimes questions. But to delete your own chat comment, after a very short time period, you need to flag it for deletion and wait for approval.
Why is there such a stricter rule for chat comments? Can you request to delete your own comment for any various reasons in the case something bothers you (not for fun)?

Answer (score 3):

> Can you request to delete your own comment for any various reasons in the case something bothers you (not for fun)?

Yes, just click the arrow next to it and use the "flag for moderator" box and request deletion there. That usually can get it deleted pretty quickly.

> Why is there such a stricter rule for chat comments?

I don't think there's a reason; the systems were probably just designed that way (and can be changed if you [put up a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=feature-request&title=Allow%20us%20to%20delete%20our%20own%20chat%20messages%20after%205%20minutes)).

However,  there is something to be said for keeping chat conversations untampered. Comments are supposed to contain suggestions and short discussions, nothing more. They are ephermal, so SE doesn't care much about deleted comments. Mass deletion of comments generates a flag. On the other hand, if someone went and mass-deleted their past chat messages, nothing would happen (there's no framework for auto flags in chat). Now, I'm not sure how much we care about chat deletion. But given that chat comment deletion after the 5 minute period is a rare case, the current system seems OK to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the "reputation points threshold" is, but higher-rep users can certainly delete their own comments without moderator intervention.

One possible justification is that deleting *your own* comment may "invalidate" comments from *other* users. Only moderators can delete other people's comments, but it's not unreasonable to suppose high-rep users might be more aware of the problems that can be caused by removing only part of an interconnected exchange of comments.

That's to say, perhaps [TPTB](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=TPTB) think low-rep users might inadvertently cause the remaining entries in a "comment thread" to become incomprehensibly disjointed, whereas they trust high-rep users to flag any "orphaned" comments following a deletion, so a mod can tidy things up properly.

Comment: You appear to be describing the rules for deleting comments on questions and answers.  However, this question appears to be about the [chat system](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), to which different rules apply.